# Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-recovery, encryption

I've lost the password to one of my wallets (it's a small one, don't worry). I was sure I remembered the password ... but evidently I don't.

Is there a program that I can use to brute-force my password, given hints?

Meaning, suppose that I remember that my password was "abc", but in fact maybe it's "Abc" or "Abc0". I would give the cracker program the string "abc" as a hint, and it would try a lot of permutations on it until it finds the real password.

Does such a cracker program currently exist? (Reliable sources please, hopefully open source)

Comment: To clarify, are you asking about the Satoshi client?  I have a 'mywallet' that I instantly forgot the password to, but I believe it's empty.

Comment: @ChrisMoore - yeah, Satoshi/standard client.

Comment: If you don't want the password to exist anywhere outside your brain, you should use a spaced repetition software to memorize it. (Ideally the software should be able to check your input against a stored hash, and used on a computer permanently disconnected from the internet)

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld and what does this have to do with this question?

Comment: @Lohoris: That it proposes alternative solutions to its premise. I am under the impression that this is acceptable use for comments.

Comment: I had to google "spaced repetition".  Found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition and thought a link here might be useful.

Comment: @Meni: At this point, the password does not exist anywhere outside his brain (and possibly no longer inside, either) :-)

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, but this circumstance can be prevented for the future, in theory at least.

Comment: FYI - luckily enough, the password _was_ indeed stored on my Keepass. I just named the entry "wallet" and not "bitcoin", so when I searched for it it didn't come up. But the question is still relevant.

Comment: Yeah!   

+1 for KeePass!

Comment: Yup, question is still relevant.  Here's another unfortunate story: http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/rqymz/forgot_my_walletdat_password_how_to_fix

Answer (score 8):

Revalin made available a sript that you can try running:

- http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=85495.msg942171#msg942171

There may not yet be anything else, but you'ld probably find someone willing to write one if you offered to send your wallet along with what you think the pass phrase might be and ask only for a fraction of the wallet's bitcoins back once cracked.

Comment: Make sure that the "someone" is trustworthy - at least if you want to get your coins back.

Comment: Depending on how wallet encryption works, you don't need to actually send the wallet itself, but only the header.

Comment: Much better to ask that person to write a script for him, in exchange for a fixed amount.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is btcrecover, available [on GitHub here](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover#btcrecover--). From [the Tutorial](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#btcrecover-tutorial):

> btcrecover is a free and open source multithreaded wallet password recovery tool with support for Armory, Bitcoin Core (a.k.a. Bitcoin-Qt), MultiBit (Classic and HD), Electrum (1.x and 2.x), mSIGNA (CoinVault), Hive for OS X, Blockchain.info (v1 and v2 wallet formats, both main and second passwords), Bither, and Bitcoin & KNC Wallets for Android. It is designed for the case where you already know most of your password, but need assistance in trying different possible combinations.

It also supports [seed recovery](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover/blob/master/docs/Seedrecover_Quick_Start_Guide.md#seedrecoverpy) for deterministic wallets:

> seedrecover.py is a Bitcoin seed recovery tool which can take a seed with one or more mistakes in it, and recover the correct seed if not too many mistakes have been made.

<sub>Full disclosure: I am the developer of btcrecover.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

You should try walletrecoveryservices.com since that appears to do just what you want. (brute forces bitcoin wallet recovery if you forget your password, without being able to steal your bitcoins)

Comment: For a free badge, read the "About" page near the search bar. Thanks and Welcome to StackExchange!

Comment: You might want to add some links to testimonials to this answer. I have heard good things about this service but it's a good idea to be sure about it before handing over your wallet.