# Unlocking wallet, recovering password

Tags: wallet, passphrase

I want to send bitcoins, but cannot unlock my wallet. The rpc password located in \AppData\Roaming does not work. How can I unlock my wallet? Deleting the wallet.dat erases all my bitcoins, which I would like to keep.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/are-there-bitcoin-password-crackers-i-can-use-to-recover-forgotten-passwords)

Comment: I have this problem too.I have a little padlock in the corner and it asks me for a pass phrase but I have never set one, do the wallets do this automatically or something because it looks like all my coins will be lost as I cannot remember something I never knew in the beginnin

Comment: How *precisely* are you trying to send Bitcoins? And what *precisely* happens when you try to unlock your wallet? (Start *before* you were even asked to enter a password.)

Comment: @David Schwartz
Firstly sorry I do not know how to comment.
I load the wallet.
I click on send coins.
I enter the wallet address of the person I wish to send them to.
I get a message to ask me if I am sure.
I then get a pop up asking me to enter my passphrase.
I have tried to enter various things and it always comes back to say it is not right.

Answer (score 1):

If you forgot your encrypted wallet's password, there is nothing you can do.

Keep it anyway, just in case you remember it someday.

Of course, if you have a backup, you can use that one.

Comment: I think the one I used was the long string of random characters given by default. Is there no way to brute force it, even it if it takes a while?

Comment: You might be confusing the wallet key with the api password, which are different. Are you sure your wallet is encrypted? (if it is, there it no way to bruteforce it, or it would be pointless to encrypt it in the first place).

Comment: Wrong. The wallet can be bruteforced, but the encryption used by bitcoin-qt makes bruteforcing very slow (but it is still possible). Try using [this script](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=85495.msg942171#msg942171) and input some of the passwords you use on other services.

Comment: @Nicolai it can only be bruteforced if you remember vaguely the password and forgot some details, or if you have a stupid or recycled password.

Comment: @Lohoris No, it can always be bruteforced. And you can ofc bruteforce the password faster, if you know parts of it, but even if you don't, then bruteforcing will still be possible (just very slow).