# blockchain.info open "aes.json" with partial password

Tags: wallet, blockchain-wallet-app

I just changed my Identifier and password; I guess I didn't type in my password the way I remember it, because it is not letting me in. I don't know how to open this dang "aes.json" backup file they sent me. How do I open that?

Comment: Frank, please don't ask people to give you answers privately. We want to make a public, searchable archive of answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/are-there-bitcoin-password-crackers-i-can-use-to-recover-forgotten-passwords)

Comment: @Lohoris Not a duplicate because blockchain.info has its own wallet format.

Comment: You could write a Python script yourself that tries possible passwords starting from the part you remember. Read Blockchain.info's documentation on its wallet format to get started.