# Blockchain.info - Forgot My Secondary Password. How to recover it?

Tags: blockchain.info, backup, lost-wallet

I haven't accessed my blockchain.info account and I completely forgot my secondary password in order to send out bitcoins. I still have my mnemonic, but that's totally useless and **MISLEADING** as it states I can recover my Bitcoins with it. But it will not recover my secondary password on blockchain.info

How can I reset my secondary password ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blockchain.info has two separate "mnemonics", one for each password (using that term loosely, since it's not the type of permanent mnemonic every other mnemonic-capable wallet uses). I agree they don't make it at all clear that you gain a *second* one once you add a second password.

It sounds like you only have the main one. If you have completely forgotten the second password and have no old wallet backups from before you added it, then you are pretty much out of luck, sorry....

If you have some idea of what your password might be, please refer to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/are-there-bitcoin-password-crackers-i-can-use-to-recover-forgotten-passwords) instead.

Comment: Tangentially, has there been a change in mnemonic algorithm for BCI over time, or has it always been as it is now?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie Sorry, no idea. I've never looked into how they encode the password into the mnemonics.

Comment: There has been [at least three revisions with conflicting word sets and methods](https://github.com/blockchain/My-Wallet/blob/master/mnemonic.js).

Answer (score 1):

The secondary password is encoded by a mnemonic, **but**, if you change that password, the original mnemonic is still encoding the *original* password. The new password is encoded with a completely different mnemonic.

You're out of luck without brute forcing, and for that I'd check out [BTCRecover by @cgurnee](http://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover).

Comment: Looks like you answer-sniped me :)