# BitcoinCore Password crash

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, passphrase

I have a Bitcoin Core wallet. 4 days ago my password worked. Now I can't send bitcoins from my wallet: the password is wrong.  What happened?  Please help, all my money is there.  I did not change the password phrase and I am sure I remember my password.  How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>caps-lock</kbd> ?

If you do not know your password it is very difficult. If you search there are other questions like [this one](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/are-there-bitcoin-password-crackers-i-can-use-to-recover-forgotten-passwords) discussing software to possibly recover the password.

Comment: I tried Caps lock too, I had bitcoin core 0.15.0.1 and create pass, after I update to 0.15.1 and have problem with pass, but several attempts is correct, after I send bitcoins 4 day ago and pass worked, now did't work I update to 0.16, but did't work still, whats happen I don't know, I try btcrecover but nothing, I don't know what's going on

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t  have your password or private key you can never send bitcoin from your wallet