# Privatekey Recovery

Tags: recover-private-key

so the question is about btc privatekey recovery .
Is there any way to recover/re calculate privatekey using these details :

SHA-256
RipeMD-160
public key 
public address
rsz signatures ( non-identical R )
scriptsig asm & hex ...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to recover a private key using only the data generated from it. If there were, Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies would instantly collapse.

If you have a [seed phrase (AKA wallet recovery phrase)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Seed_phrase), you can *re-generate* the private key from that phrase.

---

Related:

- [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3313/13866)

Comment: is there anyother option for us to know the type of that passphrase i.e : length: 12 alphanumeric etc ...
or can we get passphrase using those details ?

Comment: @Dion, No you cannot calculate the passphrase or anything about it from the details you mentioned. The best you can do is make guesses based on the sorts of passphrases or passwords used by the person who created it. You can often find software to assist in trying guesses but it may take months or years with minimal prospect of success. As you know, a passphrase is a completely different thing from a private-key and serves a different purpose.

Comment: can you give me the links of that softwares which can helps me in guessing the passphrase .

Comment: @Dion: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3313/13866

Answer (score 0):

You can "recover" it with your seed if you have one, otherwise you need to brute-force your private key from one of your public keys which is nearly impossible.

Comment: what if I don't have the passphrase/seed?