# How can I brute force guess the passphrase for a Bitcoin Wallet (Andreas Schildbach) backup file?

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app, passphrase, lost-wallet

I have a 2013-2014 240-byte wallet backup file from Bitcoin Wallet (by )Andreas Schildbach). I generated the passphrase using a pattern of two English proper nouns and 1-2 numbers.

I cannot positively say I know the proper nouns, or the capitalization. I do not know the overall length. am not positive the numbers are adjacent in the passphrase.

I am aware of Hashcat generally, and have done basic attacks on this passphrase using my best guess wordlist and standard wordlists. What are some more advanced technique ideas I can apply to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/are-there-bitcoin-password-crackers-i-can-use-to-recover-forgotten-passwords) - e.g. BTCrecover works on Schildbach backups