# What are the constraints on Bitcoin Core's wallet passphrase?

Tags: bitcoin-core, passphrase

I know I can't send coin without my passphrase, but I have forgotten it. All I would like to know is, is the passphrase a phrase I come up with? Or does Bitcoin Core provide the phrase? Many thanks.

Also is it just one word or a sequence of words?

Answer (score 2):

> **is the passphrase a phrase I come up with?**

Yes.

It is used to encrypt the wallet so that only you can use it.

> **is it just one word or a sequence of words?**

It is up to you what characters to type and whether it includes spaces.

The program suggests *"Please use a passphrase of **ten or more random characters**, or **eight or more words**"*  So, if you are the sort of person to heed advice, you probably chose a passphrase following one or the other of those forms.

> **I have forgotten it.**

See [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3313/13866)

Don't use any online tools.