# Where can I see the requirements for creating a password in Bitcion core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

In 2017 I created a wallet in Bitcoin core and protected it with a password. The password contains characters like ".,;". When I decided to send my bitcoins the wallet wrote an error "invalid password". Where can I see the specification/specification/clear requirements for the password to be created? I have a suspicion that the use of special characters caused problems with the wallet. Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Where can I see the specification/specification/clear requirements for the password to be created?

I suspect the source code is the best guide.

> the wallet wrote an error "invalid password".

That phrase doesn't occur in the source code of the current version (23.0).

The file [`qt\askpassphrasedialog.cpp`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/qt/askpassphrasedialog.cpp) contains the message *"The passphrase entered for the wallet decryption was incorrect."*

```
    case Unlock:
        try {
            if (!model->setWalletLocked(false, oldpass)) {
                QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Wallet unlock failed"),
                                      tr("The passphrase entered for the wallet decryption was incorrect."));
            } else {
                QDialog::accept(); // Success
            }
        } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Wallet unlock failed"), e.what());
        }
        break;
```

So far as I can see from a quick look, there's no special processing of the entered password (referred to as a passphrase in the code). So I'd certainly expect that normal punctuation like <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> would not cause any issues.

When you set a password, the code does produce the ominous warning *"Warning: If you encrypt your wallet and lose your passphrase, you will **LOSE ALL OF YOUR BITCOINS**!"*

```
        QMessageBox::StandardButton retval = QMessageBox::question(this, tr("Confirm wallet encryption"),
                 tr("Warning: If you encrypt your wallet and lose your passphrase, you will <b>LOSE ALL OF YOUR BITCOINS</b>!") + "<br><br>" + tr("Are you sure you wish to encrypt your wallet?"),
                 QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::Cancel,
                 QMessageBox::Cancel);
```

There are other questions here that ask about password recovery for Bitcoin code based on partially known passwords. Answers to those questions may be helpful.

- [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/3313/13866)