# How to recover from forgotten password for Bitcoin Wallet for Android backup?

Tags: security, private-key, wallet-recovery, encryption, bitcoin-wallet-app

Back in 2016, I had a Bitcoin wallet with a couple of euros worth of Bitcoin. I used the Android app "bitcoin wallet" to backup my wallet but I had to use a password.

This week, I found the wallet save file but I had forgotten the password.
Now I want to try to decrypt it, but the file doesn't have a `.dat` extension, it doesn't have an extension at all.

What format does Bitcoin wallet use?
And how can I try to decrypt the wallet?

I do probably know part of the password, it's just that I don't remember what numbers I put after the password.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there Bitcoin password crackers I can use to recover forgotten passwords?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/are-there-bitcoin-password-crackers-i-can-use-to-recover-forgotten-passwords)  -- Note that [BTCRecover](https://btcrecover.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) includes support for the Bitcoin Wallet for Android (Schildbach wallet) - but there are probably other tools too,.